# How to control max unconfirmed publishes using Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp

I am testing the how publisher confirm works in Spring-AMQP, trying to find How to control max unconfirmed publishes using Spring AMQP?

Basically i want pause publisher when unconfirmed messages count is greater than some limit.

it seems `rabbitTemplate.getUnconfirmed(age)` gives list of unconfirmed messages but it removes them from unconfirmed list once method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; we don't currently have an API for that, `getUnconfirned(age)` is intended to expire pending confirms older than an age.

We should probably add an overloaded method (with no argument) which just gets the unconfirmed correlation data, or a method that just returns the number of such.

Feel free to open an "improvement" [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we should be able to get something in the next release.

Comment: Thanks Gary! i will open JIRA issue and also submit a PR